# Same Javascript Variable works only when manually entered in

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've been working on a script to take text from one div on a page and enter it into another. I came across a strange problem. When I alert my FillinId variable I come up with questionTextF. However, when I try to use that value in my next variable, GrabFillinDiv, the value comes back null. If I manually enter in questionTextF instead, everything works. I can't do it this way though, because there are multiple FillinId's to grab content from.

Here's a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hzbdhxvs/

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var QuestionTypeName = "MultipleListQuestion-test";
            var FillinDivParent = document.getElementById(QuestionTypeName);
            var FillinDivChildren = FillinDivParent.getElementsByTagName("div"); 

            for (i=0; i< FillinDivChildren.length; i++){
                var FillinId = $(FillinDivChildren[i]).attr("id");
                alert(FillinId);
                var TplId = FillinId.slice(0,-1);
                var GrabFillinDiv = document.getElementById("\"" + FillinId + "\"");    
                var GrabFillinText = $("\"" + "#"+ FillinId + "\"").html();
                alert(GrabFillinDiv.innerHTML);
                $("\"" + "#"+ TplId + "\"").html(GrabFillinText);

             }

        });
```

Comment: Note that, by usual convention, only constructors should begin with uppercase.

Comment: If you are using jquery, why don't you use it???

Answer (score 1):

You are adding some quotes before and after the id. Don't do that:

```
for (i=0; i< FillinDivChildren.length; i++){
    var FillinId = $(FillinDivChildren[i]).attr("id");
    alert(FillinId);
    var TplId = FillinId.slice(0,-1);
    var GrabFillinDiv = document.getElementById(FillinId);  
    var GrabFillinText = $("#"+FillinId).html();
    $("#"+ TplId).html(GrabFillinText);
}
```

```js
var QuestionTypeName = "MultipleListQuestion-test";
var FillinDivParent = document.getElementById(QuestionTypeName);
var FillinDivChildren = FillinDivParent.getElementsByTagName("div"); 

for (i=0; i< FillinDivChildren.length; i++){
    var FillinId = $(FillinDivChildren[i]).attr("id");
    alert(FillinId);
    var TplId = FillinId.slice(0,-1);
    var GrabFillinDiv = document.getElementById(FillinId); 
    var GrabFillinText = $("#"+FillinId).html();
    $("#"+ TplId).html(GrabFillinText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="care-questionType"> 
  <form role="form"> 
    <div id="questionText">         
    </div> 
    <div id="PrimaryResponseItemList">         
      <div class="checkbox" data-repeat="responseItem" id="">
        <label id="ResponseLabel">
          <input id="ResponseCheckBox" type="checkbox" value=""/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="OtherResponseItem">
      <p id="OtherResponseLabel" ></p>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-addon">
          <input id="OtherCheckBox"type="checkbox">
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="ResponseOtherSpecifyText" class="form-control-inline care-multipleSelect-otherText" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="MultipleListQuestion-test">
    <div id="questionTextF">
      <p>Which categories best describe your racial background? (Please choose all that apply)</p>
    </div>
    <div id="responseItemF" data-repeat="true">
      <p>test</p>
      <div id="ResponseLabelF">
        American Indian or Alaskan Native
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `"\""` insertions. Instead of

```
var GrabFillinDiv = document.getElementById("\"" + FillinId + "\"");    
var GrabFillinText = $("\"" + "#"+ FillinId + "\"").html();
```

Try:

```
var GrabFillinDiv = document.getElementById(FillinId);    
var GrabFillinText = $("#"+ FillinId).html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzbdhxvs/1/